# Atomic add/removal of Index(Set) value(s) to Hash properties in Redis

Tags: indexing, redis, set, stackexchange.redis

Using **Stackexchange.redis**, how can I model an index to hash's properties such that I can atomically remove hash index values?

*Ex:*

```
Hash       -> Key=1    Value={ FirstName="Bob", LastName="Smith", Etc=...}
              Key=2    Value={ FirstName="Sue", LastName="Smith", Etc=...}

Set(index) -> Key=FirstName:Bob    Value={1}
              Key=FirstName:Sue    Value={2}
              Key=LastName:Smith   Value={1,2}
```

In the above example, when a new Hash is added with a value of `LastName:Smith`, I can use `.StringAppend()` to add a value to its corresponding index(Set).

In the event I need to remove Hash with `Key=2`, how do I atomically remove `2` from the values stored in the index(Set) `Key=LastName:Smith`?

Do I need to adjust my model to accommodate a more efficient index for the purpose of querying Hashes by property?

Any adjustment to my verbiage that adds clarity is also appreciated.

*~Thanks*

**Update with what I Learned:**

- A `Set` is only the Value portion of a `Key/Value Pair`(my terminology).
- Redis has commands to operate on `Members` of `Sets`.  Specifically `SADD` and `SREM`.  I do not have to operate on the `Value` in its entirity thusly prompting this SO question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need atomicity, you have to use EVAL or MULTI. For example:

### Add element

```
eval "redis.call('hset',KEYS[1],KEYS[2],KEYS[3],KEYS[4],KEYS[5]) redis.call('sadd',KEYS[2]..':'..KEYS[3],KEYS[1]) redis.call('sadd',KEYS[4]..':'..KEYS[5],KEYS[1])" 5 3 FirstName Bob LastName Marley
```

> 127.0.0.1:6370> smembers LastName:Marley
>   1) "3"
>   127.0.0.1:6370> hgetall 3
>   1) "FirstName"
>   2) "Bob"
>   3) "LastName"
>   4) "Marley"

### Remove element

```
eval "local k2=redis.call('hget',KEYS[1],KEYS[2]) local k3=redis.call('hget',KEYS[1],KEYS[3]) redis.call('srem',KEYS[2]..':'..k2,KEYS[1]) redis.call('srem',KEYS[3]..':'..k3,KEYS[1]) redis.call('del',KEYS[1])" 3 3 FirstName LastName
```

> 127.0.0.1:6370> hgetall 3
>   (empty list or set)
>   127.0.0.1:6370> smembers LstName:Marley
>   (empty list or set)

Comment: So for the removal, I would have a LUA script that does something along the lines of a GET on the Set, (use LUA foo to remove a single key from inside the Set value - Likely a string replace??)  and then SADD the Set back?

Comment: Added example script for deletion to the answer.